# How can I search a record and display the result in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have prepared a database and trying to search for a record using Ms Access forms.

I need to search the data using customer_No and display the rest of the result in the text box.

Comment: post your code regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using SQL statement and `customer_No` is an `int` column so for searching on `customer_No` use this query

```
SELECT 
    yourcolumn1, yourcolumn2,..... 
FROM
    yourtableName 
WHERE
    customer_No = 5
```

This query will return records of `customer_No` 5, if `customer_No` is text column, then use `customer_No ='5'` instead of `customer_No = 5`

Comment: Thanks for the info, the problem is that I am new to access and I am trying to search for data using customer_no by clicking on a button and display the result (Customer name) in another textbox